# How to loop through specific range of rows with Python csv reader?

Tags: python, csv

How to loop through a specific range of rows with Python csv reader?

The following code loops through all rows:

```
with open(trainFile, 'rt') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print (', '.join(row))
```

I wish to loop only from given (i to j).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
import itertools

i, j = 10, 20
with open(trainFile, 'rt') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in itertools.islice(spamreader, i, j+1):
        print (', '.join(row))
```

Alternative (following code is possible because csv.reader accept an iterable):

**NOTE**: only works when CSV rows do not contain newline.

```
import itertools

i, j = 10, 20
with open(trainFile, 'rt') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(itertools.islice(csvfile, i, j+1),
                            delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print (', '.join(row))
```

Comment: @kworr, Thank you for comment. I mention that.

Comment: In your alternative the values of `i` and `j` aren't referenced...so I doubt it works as shown.

Comment: @martineau, Thank you for pointing it out. I updated the alternative accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Use `islice`, eg:

```
rows_1_to_50 = itertools.islice(spamreader, 0, 50)
for row in rows_1_to_50:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Another itertools implementation using `dropwhile` and `takewhile`

```
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile
trainFile = 'x.1'
low_lim = 3
high_lim = 6
with open(trainFile, 'rt') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    g = (x for x in enumerate(spamreader, 1))
    g = dropwhile(lambda x: x[0] < low_lim, g)
    g = takewhile(lambda x: x[0] <= high_lim, g)
    for row in g:
        print (', '.join(row[1]))
```

Comment: When you say `trainFile = 'x.1'` that refers to the complete path, correct?

Comment: @MattO'Brien, that's correct. Could be complete or relative